# What is the better definition of absolute value should be i give to my students?

Tags: real-analysis, definition, absolute-value

The absolute value has two distincts definitions as shown below :

> > **Definition 1:**
> >     $|x|=\begin{cases} x, & 
> > \mbox{if }x \geq0 \\ -x, & \mbox{if }x< 0
> > \end{cases}$
> >
> > **Definition 2:**
> >     $|x|=\begin{cases} x, & 
> > \mbox{if }x \geq0 \\ -x, & \mbox{if }x\leq 0
> > \end{cases}$

As shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value) the definition 2 is the generalisation for ordered ring and it used widely in real analysis , but the definition 1 is rarely used at teachers and students , then my question here is :

> > **Question:**
> >     What is the better definition of absolut  value should be i give to my students ?

**Note:** I prefer to use the definition 1 to avoid repetution of  $0$ in two sides

Comment: I don't see how these definitions are ever different. Even for ordered rings the first one is fine.

Comment: Show them both and ask them to argue that both definitions result in the same function. :)

Comment: If you want to avoid a piecewise-defined definition you could use $|x| = \sqrt{x^2}$

Comment: I prefer $2$ precisely because of the repetition. This forces you to think a little. It is also more symetric like is $$\begin{cases}x>0\to +x\\x=0\to0,\\x<0\to-x\end{cases}$$

Comment: Or just go with $x \mapsto \max(-x, x)$. For the most elementary non-piecewise-definition.

Comment: Your two definitions are the same; no one is a generalization of the other. I fail to understand what is the problem and why/how one definition could be better than the other.

Comment: @Olivier, I don't cited the problem completely, in my country they forbid us as teachers for using the first definition that is the reason which let me to ask and confirm what i gave to my students

Comment: @Youssra Thank you for your answer. I would be interested in learning more about the context. Do you know why the first definition is forbidden? Are there published guidelines about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two definitions say *exactly* the same thing. This is also the same:
$$|x|=\begin{cases} x, & 
\mbox{if }x >0 \\ -x, & \mbox{if }x\leq 0
\end{cases}$$

Your students should, most importantly, understand that $|x-y|$ is the distance between $x$ and $y$ on the real line.